# How can i Remove Paid Membership Pro Footer Watermark imgae from Dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, membership

How can I remove the information of theme developer from footer of purchased theme in Wordpress?

Comment: Presumably you **buy** the plugin so it gets removed legitimately.

Answer (score 0):

At first, locate the folder of your theme.

Usually, you can find at **/.../wp-content/themes/name-of-theme**.

**Search for the footer.php** file and edit it.

**Search for the code** that make reference to the information that you want remove or modify.

**Save and test it.**

Tip: Use the **FileZilla** to access the files in server.

Comment: I'd advise on holding on on answering questions about dubious actions like this until we know they user is not trying to violate the terms of the plugin.

Comment: Yeah. Sure. The plugin or theme should have been purchased. 
I am trying to change the question to:
How can I remove the information of theme developer from footer of purchased theme in Wordpress?

Comment: This question is of too low quality to even try to salvage. No matter how you change it, it is still asking for help in violating the terms of the plugin. Even if the motive wasn't dodgy, it shows no research effort whatsoever, and even worse, no attempt at helping *us* to help them - its practically "*I want this, do it for me*". Just flag it for closing and spend your time helping users who have put some effort into their questions.